# relation between Arraylist and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

What is the relation between **List and Array**. Why i am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.?

> Basically i am passing one argument to a method, based on that using HQL, i am returning one set of **ArrayList**. Now my problem is that. when this ArrayList returns more than 0 (size)  this is working exactly the way i want.
>
> But when it returns 0 (size) ArrayList, i am getting Exception.  why is that. can any body explain to me

Now i got one more doubt like if an arraylist returns 5(first) & 0(second as size i tested up to) i am not getting any Exception. but when it returns like 200 or more elements its getting exception. why is that? **Is there any specific constant no. like up to this many elements array shouldn't give IndexOutofBounds and things like that**? can any body explain to me?

here is my code:

```
  public void setUpDisplay()
  {
    if (_flatView || _expired || _issue){ // these are all my views.
        _deptBalances = fetchBalances(null);
    }
    else if (_searchGen.getGenericName() != null){ 
        _storeGenList.clear();
        _deptBalances = fetchBalances(_searchGen.getGenericName());
        if (!ListUtil.nullOrEmptyList(_deptBalances)){
            // i am displaying the result here.
        }
        else {
            displaying error message.
        }
    }
      // here i am using my _deptBalances to display(i am just putting this list into displaygroup).
}
```

// here is my method.

```
    public List<DEPTStoreBalance> fetchBalances(String genName){
    EntityManager em // Creating instance to entity manager.
    List <DEPTStoreBalance> tempList = ListUtil.list();
    String expClause =  new String();
    if (_expired){
        expClause = "and gg.bSubjectToExpiration=true " +
                    "and msb.expirationDate <= :expDate ";
        if(_expiringOnly){
            expClause = expClause.concat(" and msb.expirationDate > :today");
        }
        else {
            expClause = expClause + 
                        "and (msb.expirationDate > :today " +
                        "or (balance.qtyBalance > 0 or balance.qtyInTransit > 0)) ";
        }
    }
    else {
        expClause = "and ((gg.bSubjectToExpiration=true " +
                    "and msb.expirationDate > :expDate) " +
                    "or gg.bSubjectToExpiration=false) ";

        if (_flatView || _issue){
            expClause = expClause.concat("and (balance.qtyBalance > 0 or balance.qtyInTransit > 0) ");
        }
        else if (genName != null){
            expClause = expClause.concat("and gg.genericName = :genName ");
        }
    }

    String hql = "select balance from DEPTStoreBalance as balance " +
                 " "+ // here are my joins with multiple tables.
                 "where dsg.store = :store " +
                 expClause;

    if (_issue)
        hql = hql.concat(" and dsi.deptIssue = :deptIssue");
    Query q = em.createQuery(hql);
    q.setParameter("store", _store); // here i am selecting the store(which is being changing in search component).
    if (_issue)//Only saleable items should be issued
        q.setParameter("expDate",12 months);
    else 
        q.setParameter("expDate",_minExpDate ); // constant value :3
    if (_expired)
        q.setParameter("today", new Date());
    if (genName != null){
        q.setParameter("genName", genName);
    }
    if (_issue)
        q.setParameter("deptIssue", true);

    try{
        tempList = (List <DEPTStoreBalance>) q.getResultList();
    }
    catch (NoResultException nre){
        //do something
    }
    finally {
        em.close();
    }       
    return tempList;        
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that generates the error?

Comment: Can anybody explain this question to me?

Comment: As i mentioned i am returning one array list. if an array list returns 5 elements first time and 0 elements next time without clearing the array, the exception is not occurring. <Br/> But if the array list returns more elements like 200 first time and 0 elements next time, i am getting the exception. <Br> This first time second time means, i am using array for search component. If i search for an item without clearing the array list, i am getting the exception. <Br>why is that? that's what my question.

Comment: @Pesula That depends on how your code is looking. Show some code and it will be a lot easier to help you. Can't say what you are doing wrong if I don't see your code. But I think there's an error in how you are performing the search.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code, there's no way that it will even compile if it looks like that.

Comment: I am **sorry** @SimonAndréForsberg, because i tried to put my own and simple words in that i was unable to explain clearly. This is my exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist is a dynamic array. Array has fixed size where as Arraylist is not.

Example:
   if you declare array as

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
```

you have to provide the size of an array.

```
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
  if(al.size()>0) { 
   // do your things 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayList is nothing but a dynamically growing array.

You're experiencing an ArrayIndexOutofBoundException because when you receive an empty list and you're trying to access a particular location *which is non-existent*, JVM throws you an exception complaining that you've crossed the bound of the internal array *a.k.a* ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

For example, in your case, when you've an empty ArrayList, the size of the list would be 0. However if you try to access an index which is >= 0, JVM will throw an ArrayIndexOutofBoundException

Comment: accessing index 0 in an empty array will also cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Correct, wasn't thinking straight I guess :) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Hi @Sujay & @ Simon André Forsberg, thanks for ur answers. Now i got one more doubt like if an arraylist returns 5(first) & 0(second as size i tested) i am not getting any Exception. but when it returns like 200 or more elements its getting exception. why is that? `Is there any specific constant no. like up to this many elements array shouldn't give IndexOutofBounds and things like that?` can u explain to me?

Comment: @Pesula No, that's not how it works. So have a look at how your indexes are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` internally uses `array` to store its content. `ArrayList` is basically sort of dynamic `array`.

If you try to access an element at `index` which is not available, you will get `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `List` has, say, 3 members and you are `calling list.get(5)` the exception is thrown. It is because the `ArrayList` is implemented by Java array.